# On Windows 7 install mktexpk places fonts under \users\userid......

Tags: fonts, texlive

I have an installation of Texlive on a Windows 7 system.  `TEXMFHOME` is set to `C:/texlive/whb/texmf`.  When I run `mktexpk --mfmode cx --bdpi 300 --mag 1+180/300 --dpi 480 cmr12` it finds the fonts in the `TEXMFHOME` tree ok, but it places the results in `C:/Users/Bill/.texlive2010/texmf-var/fonts/pk/cx/public/cm/cmr12.480pk`.

This is a problem for me because I want to use this with Mediawiki on a server and the user there will be the `IIS_USERS` account.  When I try to run under IIS, `mktxpk` fails trying to create the directory: 
`C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.texlive2010/texmf-var`

Is there some way to tell `mktexpk` to place the fonts under `TEXMFHOME`?  Or some other specific directory tree?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  VARTEXFONTS controls where the fonts are placed; VARTEXFONTS is set as TEXMFVAR/fonts.  So all you have to do is change the setting of VARTEXFONTS in texmf.cnf -- or in one of the precursor files if you want to reconfigure.

Comment: It's probably even better to change `TEXMFVAR` directly (o something writable, obviously): fonts are not the only things place in `TEXMFVAR`. But I don't recommend setting it to the same location as `TEXMFHOME`.